# Bug in torch7 gnuplot package? (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: computer-vision, gnuplot, torch

It seems that gnuplot is rounding all floating values to ints. When plotting lines or surfaces, *e.g* with these two lines from the [documentation](https://github.com/torch/gnuplot/blob/master/doc/plotline.md#gnuplot.line.dok)

```
x=torch.linspace(-2*math.pi,2*math.pi)
gnuplot.plot(torch.sin(x))
```

I obtain [image]

instead of
[image]

As expected, `print(torch.sin(x):type())` says that the tensor is indeed a `torch.FloatTensor`, so I don't understand where that rounding can be happening.

I tried the latest torch7 version and installed gnuplot using luarocks, but the results were the same. I don't think the problem is gnuplot itself, since for example, I can use it from octave without any problems.

Comment: I don't have any issues with this code. Can you print `torch.sin(x)` to see if the values are correct?

Comment: and it is not really about rounding, sin(-2*pi) should be 0 not -1, idem for sin(2*pi) which is not 1

Comment: Yes the values are correct. You are absolutely right about the sin(x) thing, but that is why I chose the word rounding, not ceil or floor. I admit this wasn't a good choice either, though. I don't know how it decides to round towards a lower or higher value, but from what I've seen (e.g. by observing plots of training errors), it is incapable of representing floating values.  The gross hack that I use is just to multiply my values by a very large factor, so I can see what happens in the plot...

Comment: Well this is strange... What version of gnuplot do you have on your computer (`gnuplot --version`)? If you're not fully satisfied with your hack ou can have a look at the display package (https://github.com/szym/display#plotting) which provides nice functions to plot curves, to zoom, etc...

Comment: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3. Thanks for the tip, the package looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. The locale that was used by default was French, thus floating point numbers were expressed using commas instead of points (*e.g.* 1,2 instead of 1.2). It appears that this caused Gnuplot to truncate the numbers (it discarded everything after the comma). So, the solution is just

```
os.setlocale('C')
```